# How to use the .serialize() method to send form values to PHP via an AJAX request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using the `.serialize()` method to serialise my form's values and send them to my PHP script in an AJAX request.

**My form:**

```
<form name="myform" action="" method="post" class="form">
    <input type="text" name="one" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="two" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="three" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**My AJAX request:**

```
$( '.form' ).on( 'submit', function( e ) {

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: ajax_url,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        'action': $action,
        'querystr': $( this ).serialize()
    }...
```

In my PHP script, I expected to be able to do something like this `$one = $_REQUEST['one']` but when I do that the value of `$one` is `null`.

Why doesn't `$_REQUEST['one']` contain the value of my form's input field?

Comment: this in this context isn't the form. it's the ajax request you may wanna do a little trick where you say var form = this; then form.serialize()

Comment: What `var_dump($_REQUEST);` outputs?

Comment: You're passing the serialized element into the 'querystr' element, so shouldn't you first get it: `$queryst = $_POST['querystr'];`, then decode it: `$queryst = json_decode($queryst);` and then access to its values? `echo $queryst['one']`. Also, as Su4p said, you're not serializing correctly

Comment: As @briosheje wrote, the data of the form sent within `querystr` POST parameter. So you can access `'one'` field on server-side by: `$_POST['querystr']['one']`

Comment: Thanks, I'm now serialising properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On php end

```
$params = array();
parse_str($_POST['querystr'], $params);
echo $params['one'];
```

Answer (score 1):

It's all in your ajax call. In the 'data' property , you declare the post fields that are sent to PHP. So in your code:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: ajax_url,
dataType: 'json',
data: {
    'action': $action,
    'querystr': $( this ).serialize()
}
```

You declare

```
 $_POST['action']
```

, and

```
 $_POST['querystr'].
```

Thats why $_POST['one'] is null - because it's not sent/defined etc.

Comment: Thank for the feedback, I opted to use PHP's `parse_str` as my solution.